# data.table bug in difference between I(x) := y and `:=`(I(x) = y)

Tags: r, data.table

Came across what I think is a bug in data.table:

Reproducible example:

```
d.test <- data.table(a = 1:5)
newName <- "Moose"
```

This works:

```
d.test[, I(newName) := a + 1]
```

This does not:

```
d.test[, `:=`(I(newName) = a + 1)]
```

Is there a reason why the second version doesn't work? Is this a bug or is there something more subtle in the way data.table works that I'm missing?

Comment: `I(newName)` is a function call. You can't have a call as the LHS of `=`. That's not specific to data.table.

Comment: @Roland, I think this is the more appropriate answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need the `I` wrapping showed in the OP's post

```
d.test[, (newName) := a + 1]
```

Or

```
d.test[, `:=`(eval(newName),.(a + 1))]
d.test
#   a Moose
#1: 1     2
#2: 2     3
#3: 3     4
#4: 4     5
#5: 5     6
```

---

If there are more number of columns,

```
newName2 <- paste0("Moose", 1:3)
d.test[, (newName2) := .(a + 1, a + 2, a + 3)]
```

Or using the second way

```
d.test[, `:=`(eval(newName2),.(a + 1, a + 2, a + 3))]
d.test
#   a Moose Moose1 Moose2 Moose3
#1: 1     2      2      3      4
#2: 2     3      3      4      5
#3: 3     4      4      5      6
#4: 4     5      5      6      7
#5: 5     6      6      7      8
```

Comment: Are you sure the first way works? When I do it it gives a new column called "newName", not "Moose". Putting brackets around the name in the first example works, but if I have many of these then I'll have to do lots of individual lines of code.

Comment: @Shillington  Sorry, I didn't notice it.  The first method works fine.  If there are more number of columns, you can do that as in the updated version

Comment: I did not downvote. Thanks for your expanded answer.

Answer (score 5):

`I(newName)` is a function call. You can't have a call as the LHS of `=`. That's not specific to data.table.

The language definition doesn't say it explicitly when describing function evaluation, but it [says for formal arguments](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Syntax-and-examples):

> a statement of the form ‘symbol = expression’

In your example we have:

```
is.symbol(quote(I(newName)))
#[1] FALSE
is.call(quote(I(newName)))
#[1] TRUE
```

To illustrate it also doesn't work in base R:

```
foo <- "bar"
list(I(foo) = 1)
Error: unexpected '=' in "list(I(foo) ="
```

This shows that the parser doesn't expect `=` after a call.